# Android Facebook SDK profile.getId() returning the wrong ID

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My facebook profile is https://www.facebook.com/nathan.moore.5209. I am using the Facebook SDK version 4.9. When I use `Profile.getCurrentProfile.getId()` I get `1115799235114823` but if I use `findmyfbid.com` and put in `www.facebook.com/nathan.moore.5209` it tells my ID is `100000542702029` which is what I should be getting.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: That is an app scoped user ID. All APIs just return app scoped user IDs. Why do you need the other ID?

Comment: I want users to be able to open a facebook messenger chat to other users and to do this I need the other ID.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately

Comment: I found this website that can convert app scoped user ID's to the real user ID's. Is there any way I can send and get the information from this website from the app?

The website is http://fber.biz/en/tool/get-facebook-id-from-scoped

Comment: Thanks I will report it

Comment: What do you mean by you will report it?

Comment: They are scraping Facebook which is not allowed

Comment: Facebook created app scoped user IDs for a reason. If there was a way to get the real ID then it would be no reason to do it

Comment: But it is useful for developers

Comment: No. An API for opening messenger from an app scoped user ID would be useful

Comment: yes but facebook have not released that, nor can you open to a facebook profile with an app scoped ID

Comment: Correct. But that is the thing you should complain about. App scoped user ids was added for a reason and Facebook will not make it easy to get the real id